# Created a new shell script but am getting permission denied when I run it. Giving myself permission is no problem, but how about others?

Tags: git, shell

Title sums it up. I've written two basic scripts that our package.json references. I have to change permissions on the script locally in order for it to work. However, these need to be merged with our codebase and everyone will need permission to execute the script. I'm not sure how to go about this?

```
/bin/sh: 1: scripts/extract.sh: Permission denied
```

I get this basic error and can obviously fix with a

```
chmod +x scripts/extract.sh
```

but other will have to do the same, unless there's way to do this so that no one else has to?

The package.json references these scripts like so:

```
  "scripts": {
    "extract": "scripts/extract.sh",
    "compile:languages": "scripts/compile-languages.sh",
```

and I just run `yarn compile:languages`, for example.

Comment: You did not say, **how** you run the script. Also plese remove the bash tag; there is no bash involved in your problem. The error message clearly says _/bin/sh_ and not _bash_.

Comment: Alright, edited. Let me know if I'm missing anything else, sorry about that.

Comment: You should add the _yarn_ tag, because your problem seems to be related on how to configure yarn to execute the script. I don't know yarn, so I can't recommend much. If you don't want to give executable writes, you would have to trick yarn into running `sh script/extract.sh` instead of `script/extract.sh`. In this case, only read permissions are needed.

Comment: Have you done any more research? There must be some other projects that do this.

Comment: Git tracks the executable status. If you `git add` an executable copy, anyone who checks that copy out will get an executable copy.

Comment: @jthill Thank you. I probably could have way simplified the question with just "does git track executeable status". Or in that case a quick google search. I appreciate it!